# Using Django ORM inside Tornado, "syncdb" doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-models, tornado

I'm using Django ORM inside Tornado, and everything is going well except that "syncdb" doesn't work.

So this is my directory structure:

```
APP_NAME/
    APP_NAME/
        models.py
        settings.py
        __init__.py
    manage.py
    database.db
```

When I do `python manage.py syncdb`, the message shows:

```
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

And the `database.db` file is created (I'm using splite3), but no tables are created.  It's worth noting that if I introduced some syntax error into `models.py`, syncdb would complain, so it seems like syncdb is able to find my `models.py`.  It's just that it's not creating tables for some reason.

For your reference, here is my settings.py (the only thing I omitted is SECRET_KEY):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'APP_NAME',
)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'database.db',
    }
}
```

Thank you.

P.S. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using Python 3.3.1 + Django 1.5.1 + Tornado 3.0.1

Comment: can you show us the models.py ?

Answer (score 0):

if you did

```
   django-admin startproject foobar
```

then your settings should look like :

```
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'foobar',
   )
```

then

```
   python manage.py syncdb
```

will give you

```
   Creating tables ...
   Creating table auth_permission
   Creating table auth_group_permissions
   Creating table auth_group
   Creating table auth_user_groups
   Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
   Creating table auth_user
   Creating table django_content_type
   Creating table django_session
   Creating table django_site
   Creating table foobar_mymodel
```